# If $\left(1+x^{2}+x^{4}\right)^{8}={^{16} C_{0}}+{^{16}C_{1}} x^{2}+{^{16} C_{2}} x^{4}+\cdots +{^{16} C_{16}} x^{32}$, how to prove...

Tags: binomial-theorem

If I am given that $$\left(1+x^{2}+x^{4}\right)^{8}={^{16} C_{0}}+{^{16}C_{1}} x^{2}+{^{16} C_{2}} x^{4}+\cdots +{^{16} C_{16}} x^{32},$$
how can I prove that $${^{16} {C}_{1}}+{^{16} {C}_{4}}+{^{16} {C}_{7}}+{^{16} {C}_{10}}+{^{16} {C}_{13}}+{^{16}{C}_{16}}=3^{7}$$ is true?

**My approach:** I usually try to evaluate these by putting $x =\sqrt{-1}, \sqrt[3]{-1}$ however I'm not sure how to approach this. Please suggest any hints or methods as to how to solve this particular and in general how to approach these types of expressions.

Comment: try $x=\omega$ where $\omega$ is complex cube root of $1$

Comment: What you’re given is $(1+x^2)^{16} = (1+2x^2 +x^4 )^8 \ne (1+x^2 +x^4)^8 $.

Comment: @Tavish Not sure if that's true but if it is then probably they just want us to assume a hypothetical system I think

Comment: @ashish It is true.

Comment: @IITM I did that to prove another result which was $^{16} \mathrm{C}_{0}+^{16} \mathrm{C}_{3}+^{16} \mathrm{C}_{6}+^{16} \mathrm{C}_{9}+^{16} \mathrm{C}_{12}+^{16} \mathrm{C}_{15}=3^{7}$ not sure how I can apply it to prove the result above

Comment: What you wrote above is not actually true. If you could show your steps, we can better help you.

Comment: The given series does not sum to $3^7$.

Comment: @TobyMak first took $x = \omega$ then took $x = \omega^2$ then took $x = 1$. LHS in the first two were zero and in the second was 3^8. Now I add all these three equations. then $(1 + \omega + \omega^2) = 0$ so the C1,C2 etc. equal 0. And then divide the result by 3. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Oh btw, the original series could probably not be summing to that. I think there is some error in the question that they have added $^{16} \mathrm{C}_{0}$ instead of just writing $\mathrm{C}_{0}$ (which could technically mean any constant ?). This might probably solve the issue even @Tavish had. However what I posted above was the question given to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left(1+x^{2}+x^{4}\right)^{8}={^{16} C_{0}}+{^{16}C_{1}} x^{2}+{^{16} C_{2}} x^{4}+\cdots +{^{16} C_{16}} x^{32}$

I  took the equation given by @ashish,also it is wrong as pointed out by@Tavish

put $x=\omega$

$(1+\omega^2+\omega^4)^8={^{16} C_{0}}+{^{16} C_{1}} \omega^2+{^{16} C_{2}} \omega^4+\cdots$

$0=\omega^2({^{16} {C}_{1}}+{^{16} {C}_{4}}+{^{16} {C}_{7}}+{^{16} {C}_{10}}+{^{16} {C}_{13}}+{^{16}{C}_{16}})+\omega(^{16} {C}_{2}+\cdots)+(^{16}{C}_{0}+\cdots)$      ($1$)

by comparing with equation $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$

the coeffecients of $\omega,\omega^2,1$ are equal(this can also be proved by taking imaginary and real parts in above equation).so as You said you got $(^{16}{C}_{0}+\cdots)$the same value is for the required series.

all the numbers are  as per the question so the values may not be equal but this answer is to know the method

Comment: Hey @IITM please check with my last comment do you think that is the problem with the equation ?

Comment: @ashish I think they are $a_1,a_2,...$

Comment: Is your username signifying IIT madras LOL

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore No,btw are you from India?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the powers of $x^6$ between subsequent coefficients, so I suggest dividing this polynomial by $x^6-1$ and checking the remainder. If $$ (1+x^2+x^4)^8 = {}^{16}C_0 +{}^{16}C_1 x^2 + \dots + {}^{16}C_{16} x^{32} = w(x) (x^6-1) + r(x)$$
we have
$$r(x) = a + b x^2 + c x^4$$
where
$$ a = {}^{16}C_0 +{}^{16}C_3 + \dots + {}^{16}C_{30} $$
$$ b = {}^{16}C_1 +{}^{16}C_4+ \dots + {}^{16}C_{31} $$
$$ c = {}^{16}C_2 +{}^{16}C_5 + \dots + {}^{16}C_{32} $$
If you put $x^2 \in\{1, (-1)^\frac23, (-1)^\frac43\}$ you have $x^6-1 =0 $, so
$$a + b+ c = (1+1+1)^8 = 3^8$$
$$a + b (-1)^\frac23 + c (-1)^\frac43 = (1+(-1)^\frac23+(-1)^\frac43)^8 = 0$$
$$a + b (-1)^\frac43 + c (-1)^\frac83 = (1+(-1)^\frac43+(-1)^\frac83)^8 = 0$$
Solving these equations gives you
$$ a = b= c= 3^7$$